# IIS slow multithreading

Tags: asp.net, .net, multithreading, iis, worker-process

We have a .NET application which is calling over OpenRia services on the server (IIS). This web service call is running a heavy calculation, where we are loading over LoadLibrary some DLL's, which we need to solve some linear systems. We need to go over a list of 1000 events. Every single event is a separate calculation and can be run independently from each other.
What we are doing is, that we create on a 64-core machine 60 tasks and every task is taking one event => run the calculation => take the next event => run the calculation and so on until the list is empty.
As soon the list is empty our calculation is finished.

We have now the strange behaviour that on the first run the calculation seems to run fast, but when we run the same calculation again it's getting slower on every run.
If we restart the server the calculation is running fast again.

We have done an analysis with PerfView and we have seen that on the second/third/fourth run the used threads from the IIS worker process are less than at the beginning.
On the first run the IIS worker process is using 60 threads (as we have defined) and on the second the process is using less than 60. On every run the actual threads used are less and less.
The first run the calculation needs around 3min. The second run we need 6min and the third run we are already around 15min.

What could be the problem? I have tried to use the ThreadPool, but I have the same effect as with the Tasks.

Here is some sample code:

```
//This part of code is called after the web service call
ConcurrentStack<int> events = new ConcurrentStack<int>();//This is a list of 1000 entries
ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
int interfacesDone = 0;
Task[] tasks = new Task[options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism];
for (int i = 0; i < options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism; i++)
{
  tasks[i] = Task.Run(() =>
  {
      StartAnalysis(events);
  });
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);


private void StartAnalysis(ConcurrentStack<int> events)
{
     while (!events.IsEmpty)
     {
         int index;
         if (events.TryPop(out index))
         {
             DoHeavyCalculation();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: IIS itself utilizes the thread pool to handle incoming requests, so it allocates dedicate threads and make sure they are available when needed. So, if your web app also wants to carry out heavy operations and utilizes threads (no matter which .NET multithreading API you use), you are introducing conflicts and contention. To resolve such contention, the feasible option is to redesign your web app and move heavy operations out to other processes. Anyway it won't be an easy/simple answer.

Comment: What I'm not sure about is: That we are doing just one request to the server. There are no other requests until the calculation is finished. Why is the first time so fast and the other times so slow? We will for sure try to do the calculation outside the IIS process.

Comment: "but when we run the same calculation again it's getting slower on every run. If we restart the server the calculation is running fast again." - sounds like you are not disposing of resources correctly.

Comment: If something is not disposed the memory should increase a lot. But we are around the same size after 3,4 runs. After the work is done, should the threads not be destroyed?

Comment: "If something is not disposed the memory should increase a lot." - depends. maybe a thread is hanging on to a small object?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET processes requests by using threads from the .NET thread pool. The thread pool maintains a pool of threads that have already incurred the thread initialization costs.

Therefore, these threads are easy to reuse. The .NET thread pool is also self-tuning. It monitors CPU and other resource utilization, and it adds new threads or trims the thread pool size as needed.

Comment: Is there a way to monitor that?

Comment: You can use perfomance counter to monitor threads. This [article](https://stackify.com/how-to-monitor-iis-performance/) shows many ways to monitor application and IIS. You can refer to it.